# Is there an equivalent to set_index for Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying out `pandas`, and having trouble using `concat()` (instead of the deprecated `append()`) to populate a `DataFrame` with numerous `Series`, where the name is supposed to be taken (moved) from a certain value of each `Series` (similar to `DataFrame.set_index()`)

The following code *works*, but I don't know how to replicate it with proper `pandas` usage:

```
_collection = pd.DataFrame()
with open(filename) as _f:
for _line in _f.readlines():
    # Parse the line into a dictionary
    # e.g: {"Worker ID": 123, "Name": "John Smith", "Salary ($)": 1000}
    _entry = re.match(RE_ENTRY, _line).groupdict()
    # Append the dictionary to _collection using pd.concat()
    _collection= pd.concat([_collection, pd.Series(_entry, name=_entry.pop("Work ID"))], axis=1)
return _collection
```

I found out that replacing the `name=_entry.pop("Work ID")` workaround with changing `return _collection` to `return _collection.T.set_index("Work ID").T`, but that seems redundant...

I'm assuming there's a cleaner way to do this with `pandas`, but admittedly I know very little of it!

P.S: There's probably a List Comprehension solution, but I need to adjust some values in the parsed `_entry`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_axis`:

```
>>> sr = pd.Series(list('ABCDEF'))
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
dtype: object


>>> sr.set_axis(range(8, 14))
8     A
9     B
10    C
11    D
12    E
13    F
dtype: object
```